# how to access specific raw data on java in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

I'm trying to access the master boot record sector using java and I have done it in windows but the address I used is not valid in ubuntu. this is my code:

```
File diskRoot = new File("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0");
final RandomAccessFile diskAccess = new RandomAccessFile(diskRoot, "r");
byte content[] = new byte[512];
diskAccess.readFully(content);
```

can anyone tell me what I should type instead of "\\.\PhysicalDrive0" in ubuntu?

Comment: Propably `/dev/sda`. Maybe look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/27997/which-hard-disk-drive-is-which

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to run before the below command to copy the MBR in a file:

```
$ dd if=/dev/sda of=yourMBR.bin bs=512 count=1
```

I don't know if you can avoid this step on Linux.